# How to track errors thrown by API that pushed data in a Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, triggered-send, sfmc-business-unit

If the process of added data to a data extension includes the following:

1. microsite page (with ampscript) that followes similar approach like this: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/createTriggeredSend.htm
2. In this use-case ampscript includes additional fields as well - let's say "CompanyName"
3. trigger send is pushed the data from the microsite (along with additional field - "CompanyName") to a DE

**Issue:** The incoming traffic to the microsite is pushing data correctly to the defined DE in the triggered send. But, some records that came from the microsite are not showing up in the DE. Based on troubleshooting, it looks like those records that didn't make it to the DE had "CompanyName" value characters more than what the length defined in the DE. Length is 50 and incoming values for some records was 100.

**Question:** Is there any place where I can see the error was recorded for records who didn't make it to the DE? any API endpoing?

Comment: This is only present in the response of the API call being made

Comment: Is there any log or API end point in marketing cloud that captured all API requests made?

Comment: Update: I tried the approach of pushing data to a DE via API and purposely pushed test records with character length greater than what is defined on DE in SFMC via postman. The response does not include any message or error that says record was not added. The records with error simply don't show up in the DE. [Import Row Method Used for this test via API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/insertDataExtensionIDAsync.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the triggered send API is async you will only receive a "queued" status. This would require a second call to check the status using the [deliveryRecords](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/messageDefinitionSendsDeliveryRecords.htm) route.

I forced an error in a triggered send where the value exceeded the DE column length and received the following error when I checked status: ""messageErrorStatus": "The value specified for a data extension field does not match the field type""

Comment: Thank you @Aaron Cates - This is very helpful